# how can write this stored procedure, so that would not hide the error

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

At the moment I write stored procedures this way:

```
create proc doStuff
@amount int
as
begin try
begin tran
...
if something begin  select 'not_good' rollback return end
if someelse begin  select 'some_other_thing' rollback return end
--do the stuff
...
commit 
end try
begin catch 
if @@trancount > 0 rollback
select 'error'
end catch
```

the problem with this approach is that I hide the error, anybody knows to do this some other ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL server sp.

```
create procedure doStuff
(
   @amount int
) 
as
begin try
   begin transaction

    if something
        raiserror('not_good', 16, 1)

    if somethingelse
        raiserror('some_other_thing', 16, 1)

    do stuff here

   commit
end try
begin catch
    if @@trancount > 0
        rollback

    declare @errmsg nvarchar(4000), @errseverity int
    select @errmsg = error_message(), @errseverity = error_severity()

    raiserror(@errmsg, @errseverity, 1)
end catch
```

Answer (score 3):

What database are you using? In SQL Server you can use the keyword RASIERROR to generate error messages. See [RAISERROR (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming SQL Server here, since that looks a lot like SQL Server syntax:

Preferably, you should also use `SAVE TRAN` so you can treat the procedure as its own unit of work and let the caller choose whether or not to rollback the *entire* transaction (as opposed to only rolling back the work in this particular block).  [Remus Rusanu](http://rusanu.com/2009/06/11/exception-handling-and-nested-transactions/) wrote an article about that a while back.

Putting that aside for the moment, you need to save the error immediately after you catch it and then re-raise it after rolling back (normally with some additional info):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE xyz [params]
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRAN
        -- Do the work
        COMMIT
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        DECLARE
            @Error int,
            @Severity int,
            @Message varchar(4000)
        SELECT
            @Error = ERROR_NUMBER(),
            @Severity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
            @Message = ERROR_MESSAGE()
        ROLLBACK
        RAISERROR('Procedure xyz: %d: %s', @Severity, 1, @Error, @Message)
    END CATCH
END
```

Comment: I tried not saving it immediately just like @clyc showed, and it worked

Comment: @Omu: It might be OK to execute a `ROLLBACK` in particular before checking `ERROR_NUMBER()` and the rest, but most statements will reset the error info; it's best to capture it as soon as possible.